# How to localize path to data source?

Tags: ios, swift, csv, localization

I want to localize an app that pulls data from a CSV file.

```
let location = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CSV", ofType: "txt")
```

I have other CSV files with the same data but translated into other languages. I found how to localize strings but how can I localize location of data sources?

Comment: Just put one CVS.txt file in each of the localized folders (en.lproj, fr.lproj, ...), then Bundle.main.path(forResource:...) will automatically pick the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to write the file names of the localised CSV files in `Localizable.strings`.

For example, the English version of the file can be called `CSV_en.txt`, the French version `CSV_fr.txt`.

In the English version of the strings file, write

```
"CSV" = "CSV_en";
```

In the French version write

```
"CSV" = "CSV_fr";
```

Then you can get your localised CSV file by doing:

```
let location = Bundle.main.path(forResource: NSLocalizedString("CSV", comment: ""), ofType: "txt")
```